# How to get a nice round combination of textbox and button in html/css

Tags: html, css, blazor, mudblazor

For a project, built in Blazor, I have to create a combination of an input field and a button that form a nice rounded combination, including an icon.

I am using the MudBlazor components, and was hoping to be able to leverage the capabilities of `MudTextField` and `MudButton`.  But it seems that's not possible (at least not out of the box).

Any has an idea how I could solve this, preferably with a MudBlazor component, but as a fallback, I can also use html/css.  Any help is appreciated from this backend dev, that suddenly is building a front end :)

[image: Rounded validation button]

Comment: I can find the [.rounded-r-xl and .rounded-l-xl](https://mudblazor.com/utilities/border-radius#rounding-sides) classes in the documentation. Wouldn't that work? Just add these classes to the input and button et voila, rounded!

Comment: I know, but that would make two rounded controls, where I only need the outside (left of textbox, right of button) to be rounded and the touching sides should still be straight.

Comment: You can round only the left or the right side of an element, please read the documentation more carefully. Perhaps scroll down a bit more?

Comment: thanks, @KIKOSoftware - that seems to be doing the trick indeed.  apologies for not reading through (didn't get the rounded l vs r)

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can use `rounded-l-xl` class for the rounded corners on the left side and `rounded-r-xl` class for the right side. You can also round only one corner. For example if you want to round top left corner then you need to add `rounded-tl-xl` class.

Here is [the link](https://mudblazor.com/utilities/border-radius#rounding-sides) for details.